# ng-model not working in angular ui-bootstrap star rating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple star rating input via angular ui-bootstrap. The code works fine except that the `ng-model` is not grabbing the value from the model.

Here is the markup:

```
<div ng-controller="shopperFeedbackController">
        <div class="row feedback-rating-row" >
            <div class="col-sm-16">
                <div class="feedback-label">
                    Rating:
                </div>

                <div class="feedback-rating-star-input">
                    <rating ng-model="rate" <--- Not working
                            max="max_rating" 
                            on-hover="hovering_over(value)" 
                            on-leave="overStar = null" 
                            titles="['one','two','three']" >
                    </rating>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

And the code:

```
snbApp.controller('shopperFeedbackController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.max_rating = 5;
  $scope.rate = 3;
});
```

Comment: This should be working. Are you sure the problem is with ngModel? I think there is something broken before. For example, shouldn't be `{{metric.name}}` instead of `{$ metric.name $}` ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the code be{fore submitting and I forgot the remove the {$ metric_name $}. The configured the app to use {$ instead of {{ because the app is used with django. Regardless, ngModel still doesn't work even without these modifications.

Comment: Could you create a plunkr? I checked the angular ui documentation and I replaced the rating example with your code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your code in a plunker.

The rating code is working, but you have a problem with the CSS `row` class, in the following line:

```
<div class="row feedback-rating-row">
```

See **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lfOCbWeOiqEyMh1FvWts?p=preview)**

The `row` is adding a `margin-left: -15px;` and the first star goes out of the viewport.

Comment: That's true. So he can basically fix this problem by wrapping the `row` inside of a `container`. `<div class="container" ng-controller="shopperFeedbackController">`

Comment: Well, if he was using `col-sm-*` with `*` from 1 to 12, as bootstrap has 12 columns, that would be ok. Here OP is using `col-sm-16`. Maybe he redefined the number of bootstrap columns.

Comment: The system I am working with is using customized bootstrap grid which supports up to 16 columns. I removed the row and cols, yet the code is still not working properly. The funny thing is that I can select the stars, but the ngModel attribute is not doing anything, as if it isn't there.

Comment: Which versions of angular and ui-bootstrap do you use? Could you reproduce the bug in a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

The ui-bootstrap version I was using was 0.13.3. I changed it to the latest (0.13.4) and it worked.